# Find usages from base interface method

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, resharper

I have the following interface:

```
public interace MyInterface : IDisposable
{
  // ...
}
```

Now I want to find usages of `Dispose()`, but only on instances which implements `MyInterace`, ideally from `using` syntax aswell. Is that possible using either VisualStudio or R#?

Thanks =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the "Find Usages Advanced" command (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> for VS keymap, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> for IntelliJ keymap). This will pop up a dialog that will allow you to choose between finding usages of `IDisposable.Dispose` and `MyInterface.Dispose` (among other options)

Comment: I was thinking about this aswell, but I was not able to open that dialog on the `Dispose` method on `MyInterface`. Can you tell me where I can access that?

Comment: Ah. Very good point. Not sure you can do this with an interface - I'd assumed it was a class. You could try temporarily adding a `Dispose` method to the `MyInterface` (you'll probably need the `new` keyword) and then invoke the find usages dialog on that. I don't know if this will work, though...

Comment: temporarily adding `new void Dispose();` is working for me, thanks :)

Comment: With the version 9 of R# this feature has been added!